# Mnesia Replication and Large Numbers of Dirty Operations

Tags: erlang, mnesia, yaws, mochiweb, nitrogen

Some applications require really fast response, to meet their expectations to users. I am building one such application and i am using `mnesia`. Now, when we `by-pass` the mnesia transaction manager , we approach good performance. However, this is the problem:
 We need to replicate this database as part of `load balancing`, after-all, mnesia does the replication for us. We are using `ONLY` `dirty` operations in this application. We have a few parts using `async_dirty` context. I am wondering, would mnesia replication be affected if we are not using the `transaction` context at this scale ? 
Too many frequent `dirty` operations are occuring on records all the time, so i wonder if a request made on `side B` replica, would find the changes the have just been made by `side A` replica via a dirty operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mnesia User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap4.html):

- `async_dirty` activities "will wait for the operation to be performed on one node but not the others".
- For `sync_dirty` activities: "The caller will wait for the updates to be performed on all active replicas".